# How to add options to ckeditor in backpack-for-laravel

Tags: laravel-backpack

I'd like to add text-alignments to ckeditor in Backpack for Laravel.

How can I do it?

I tried this but it did not work.

```
        $this->crud->addField([
            'name' => 'content',
            'label' => 'Content',
            'type' => 'ckeditor',
            'options' => ['alignment'],
        ]);
```

Answer (score 2):

The [docs](https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/3.6/crud-fields#ckeditor) show that `options` should be passed as an associative array.

Backpack (at least my version) uses CKeditor 4.9, and specifically, the `ckeditor.blade.php` makes use of the [CKeditor jQuery adapter](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_jquery.html).

[Here is a list of all the possible options that you can set](https://docs-old.ckeditor.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html). I couldn't find "alignment" anywhere in the documentation, but I suspect you are talking about the justify buttons in the toolbar, if that's true, your options might look something like the below:

```
$this->crud->addField([
    'name' => 'content',
    'label' => 'Content',
    'type' => 'ckeditor',
    'options' => [
        'toolbar'=>
            [
                [
                    'name'=>  'paragraph',
                    'items' =>  [
                        'JustifyLeft',
                        'JustifyCenter',
                        'JustifyRight',
                        'JustifyBlock',
                    ]
                ],
            ]
    ],
]);
```

Though, this may force you to list out all the toolbar options you want, if so, see [this section in the docs](https://docs-old.ckeditor.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html#.toolbar)